# how to sort strings in dictionary order?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting

I have a file of strings and I have to sort them in dictionary order in O(nlog(n)) or less time. I know the sorting algorithms and applied them to sort numbers. but I have no Idea how to sort strings by using Quick sort or any other sorting algorithm. 
Please provide the algorithms not built in methods.

Comment: What language you have to use? Simple `sort` function in php will sort strings in alphabetical order.

Comment: any language! I just want to know the algorithm or way.

Comment: If you have to create your own function. You can, say, assign a number to the letter. In some languages there are standart functions to do this.

Comment: then the string will become a set of numbers. and what for alphabets which has been assigned a number greater than 9?

Comment: You can assign `26` to `Z`. 1 > 26? no! So A will appear in array earlier then Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For strings, common suggestion may be [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

It strictly depends from alphabet that was used for strings forming and is `O(kN)` time complexity, where `n` is number of keys and `k` is average key length. Note, that it may be confusing to compare this with `O(n log n)` (where `n`  means *number of input elements* )

So - the lesser is `k`, the better is radix sort approach. That means, for lesser radix it will be more effective. I would just quote extended explanation (no need to rephrase it):

> The topic of the efficiency of radix sort compared to other sorting
>   algorithms is somewhat tricky and subject to quite a lot of
>   misunderstandings. Whether radix sort is equally efficient, less
>   efficient or more efficient than the best comparison-based algorithms
>   depends on the details of the assumptions made. Radix sort efficiency
>   is O(d·n) for n keys which have d or fewer digits. Sometimes d is
>   presented as a constant, which would make radix sort better (for
>   sufficiently large n) than the best comparison-based sorting
>   algorithms, which are all O(n·log(n)) number of comparisons needed.
>   However, in general d cannot be considered a constant. In particular,
>   under the common (but sometimes implicit) assumption that all keys are
>   distinct, then d must be at least of the order of log(n), which gives
>   at best (with densely packed keys) a time complexity O(n·log(n)). That
>   would seem to make radix sort at most equally efficient as the best
>   comparison-based sorts (and worse if keys are much longer than
>   log(n)).

Also, this algorithm will use some additional space (with worth space complexity `O(k+n)`) - thus, you should be aware of that (not like comparative algorithms which won't use additional space)

Comment: Thanks for the nice description. I hope this is my solution.Let me try it out/

Answer (score 0):

You look at the numerical values (ascii values) of the letters and use them to do the numerical order.

So you look at a word from left to right. If the letters match, you look at the second etc.

Comment: then the string will become a set of numbers. and what for alphabets which has been assigned a number greater than 9?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How would an alphabet have assigned numbers? The sorting algorithms from popular languages typically state that they use e.g. ASCII.